# CSS media queries for width or height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I placed a logo in the center of a full-screen-page.

```
img.logo {
        width: 920px;
        height: 552px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -460px;
        margin-top: -276px;
    }
```

This is working fine.
Now i want different sizes on different device heights and widths so i tried using media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 991px), (max-height: 460px) {
    img.logo {
        width: 235px;
        height: 141px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -117px;
        margin-top: -70px;
    }   
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px), (min-height: 300px) and (max-height: 649px) {
    img.logo {
        width: 533px;
        height: 320px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -276px;
        margin-top: -160px;
    }   
}
@media (min-width: 1200px), (min-height: 650px) { 
    img.logo {
        width: 920px;
        height: 552px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -460px;
        margin-top: -276px;
    }
}
```

But this still works if both parameters are changing at the same time.
I want it separated, so you can change the browser height and the image size changes OR the browser width OR both.

The image (the logo) should always stay in the middle of the page.

Comment: Use more commas, less ands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all those margin offsets if you centre the image in its parent this way:

```
img.logo {
   width: 350px; //or whatever
   height: 350px; //or whatever (maybe auto)
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Then you can use media queries to change **just** the image size:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    img.logo {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }   
}
```

I made a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/D6pja/)

Comment: Okay, thank you, but this just changes the image in relation to the browser width not to the height.

Comment: i got it. @media (max-width: 991px), (max-height: 680px) {...}

Comment: Using comma-separated queries is correct (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/) - its an 'or' so if either clause is met the style is applied.